# Driving resistance in Arnoldi reduced order RC models

Tags: circuit-analysis, spice, math

I am new to this community and I'm learning to write a model order reduction engine for a lumped RC network.

The network has a few nodes connected by a few resistances and capacitances. There can also be grounded capacitances. As we know, we can write the system as a G matrix and a C matrix, for conductance and capacitance respectively. This is the underlying principle of SPICE.

One way to reduce the order of this time-dependent linear system is to use Krylov subspace-based model order reduction algorithms, like the coordinate-transformed Arnoldi algorithm described in [this paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=125879195049159137b8f3b7785f4142a089843f). The result is two matrices, Hq and Uq, with smaller sizes and which approximates the waveform of the original system.

In my case, I am implementing a static timing analysis engine for digital circuit design. One of my tasks is to model the RC network behavior when it is driven by an external resistor (which we call driving resistance or Rd). The presence of Rd will add 1/Rd to the upper-left element of the matrix G.

Different G matrix will certainly lead to different reduced-order Hq and Uq matrices. But what is surprising to me is that the only affected number is the upper-left element of matrix Hq. And that number is linearly dependent on Rd. This property is actively used in industrial circuit analysis algorithms, [like this](https://github.com/The-OpenROAD-Project/OpenSTA/blob/master/dcalc/ArnoldiDelayCalc.cc#L609).

I wonder if anyone can explain to me the mathematical story under this property. Thanks.